# How redirect for content from other server, but not change URL

Tags: php, apache, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a task:
I have a Main Server hosting an application with all business logistic.

There are other server(s) (maybe cloud in the future) which act as file storage.

How can a user get some files? (But only those who the have access to).

My idea:

On ServerMain I will have Nginx (as proxy) + Apache
First user makes a request to Nginx
Nginx proxy to Apache.
Apache checks for access to the file.
If allowed, then Apache returns a redirect to another server (with path to content).
If denied, then Apache returns denied response.

So, the user can't see the link to the other server.

But that won't work for me, the user can see redirect url.

My params:
Nginx work on port 80
Apache work on port 8080

nginx config host

```
server {

        listen  127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name ap-file.loc;


        server_name_in_redirect on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
                proxy_redirect   off;
                proxy_set_header  Host $host;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                client_max_body_size 10m;
                proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        }
}
```

Code for php page, which redirected to other server

```
<?php
$newURL = 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_16lyaJiGldI/TBekxqet-JI/AAAAAAAAAis/jTGCN4Wfo8Q/s320/smile.jpg';

header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

That code worked on apache.

Tell me what am I doing wrong? May be Nginx settings?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do load balancing, if that is true hen here is a good article to do it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing Here is another one that using Nginx+Apache https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-scale-web-applications-on-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: @ryan_naddy It sounds nothing like loadbalancing. The key issue is keeping the url hidden and loadbalancing does not do that.

Comment: Yes, main task is not displayed to the customer URLs other servers with content

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**
You are using header('Location: '.$newURL); which return a header with new url to the browser (causing browser to redirect to new url)

**Solution**
Instead of providing the real URL in the location you can make a curl request to your data server and through back the output if the user is authenticated.